# How to update existing module from ODOO 11.0 version to Newest version14.0...?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, odoo-14

I'm trying to upgrade version 11 to version 14. I have one custom module, So right now I need only to update the custom module from v11 to v 14...?
Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Start by [migration to version 12.0](https://github.com/OCA/maintainer-tools/wiki/Migration-to-version-12.0).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply migrate your custom module from Odoo v11 to v14. If you are a developer, you need to make the app compatible with v14 by modifying the code as per the libraries and other parameters of Odoo v14 code. Upon successful testing, you can directly migrate your custom module to v14. In the case of Odoo upgradation, you start sequentially which may be time-consuming.